# Редирект в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день! Необходимо сделать редирект в .htaccess с /menu.php на /menu.php?id=3. Прописываю такое правило, но оно зацикливается:

```
Redirect /menu.php /menu.php?id=3
```

Как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметры не учитываются при разборе.
Я бы порекомендовал сделать изменения непосредственно в самом `menu.php`

```
if (empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = 3;
} else {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

А еще правильней, будет вынести эту три в конфиг, и получать это значение из него. Назвать что то типа `MENU_DEFAULT_ID`

Comment: Спасибо. А можно же еще с помощью mod_rewrite сделать, я просто не силен в регулярных выражениях.